# Nan is not existing in data but still it is giving me error that 'float ' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have to split a column of dataframe in pandas on basis of '|' but it gives me error that float in not iterable. There is no NAN exist in data.
I have splitted data and save it in list and traversing that list is also giving me same error.

[image: It prints data but give me error as well]

Comment: Can you also include your input data (or part of it if it is large)? From error description it sound like L is list with float numbers, so error you get would be right, you can't iterate float.

Comment: L=['Crime', 'Drama', 'Fiction'] my ist contains data like this

Comment: I have get this data from may dataframe column. I have checked for Nan in data, it returns false

Answer (score 0):

You can try to troubleshoot by using try/except statements. Here is an example of how to do so in a way that shows you which elements of your list are causing a problem.

```
L = ['Crime', 'Drama', None, 'Fiction']

L2 = []
for i in L:
    try:
        for j in i:
            L2.append(j)
    except TypeError:
        print ('object is not iterable: {0}'.format(i))
```